# SQL Joins Not Returning All Field Values; Different Field Values Returned When Order Changed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using the following SQL to query 3 simple tables and pull back results. When I run this query in SQL Server 2005 EM (database that's being used), the correct recordset results are returned. When I execute this from my webpage (ASP) via an SQL statement or a stored procedure, I get blank values for some of the columns. Also, I noticed that when I change the order of the tables being selected in my FROM clause, some of the previous columns then return blank values. Is there something wrong with my SQL for it not to work when calling it? I developed my app locally and it works fine. When I deployed it to the client's network, the problems started... The client is running Win 2000 SP4 as their application server and my app is developed in ASP 3.0 with a SQL Server 2005 datastore.

```
SELECT
Scorecard_Measure.Measure,
Scorecard_Measure.Target,
Scorecard_Measure.YTD,
Scorecard_Measure.Status,
Scorecard_Measure.Explanation,
Scorecard_Measure.Division,
Scorecard_Measure.ZIndex,
Scorecard_Measure.LastUpdated,
Scorecard_Measure.ID,
Scorecard_Objectives.Details,
Scorecard_Objectives.ZIndex,
Scorecard_ObjectiveCats.IdentityLetter
FROM
[Scorecard_Measure],
[Scorecard_Objectives],
[Scorecard_ObjectiveCats]
WHERE
Scorecard_Measure.ObjID=Scorecard_Objectives.ID
AND Scorecard_Objectives.ObjCatID = Scorecard_ObjectiveCats.ID
AND Scorecard_Measure.FiscalYear = '2011'
AND Scorecard_Measure.Publish='Y'
ORDER BY Scorecard_Measure.LastUpdated DESC
```

Scorecard_Objectives.ID is a foreign key in the Scorecard_Measure table, Scorecard_ObjectiveCats.ID is a foreign key in the Scorecard_Objectives table.

Also, a weird occurence. I have two column names that are the same and when I reference those columns, the server isn't throwing an error like I've seen before saying "your results have columns with the same name, reference them using the tables they come from"... e.g. rs("Scorecard_Objectives.ZIndex") and rs("Scorecard_Measure.ZIndex") -- when I use these references, I get an error from IIS.

Any points is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  Do you have two databases that are being confused?

Comment: @SteveWellens, no. The connection string in my application is pointed to this particular database. It's just so weird. It all worked like a charm locally on localhost. What beats me is that the query pulls back all the data when I run the query in a new query window in SQL Server...

Comment: @MarkJohnsII - I don't see you prepending the table's owner in your query. Do you perhaps have multiple schema's with identical tablenames? What happens if you prepend the owner to each table (Assuming the owner is dbo, this would become dbo.Scorecard_Measure, ...).

Comment: @Lieven, I'll try that. No, I didn't prepend the tables with dbo. That, in fact, is the owner of the tables in the datastore. These are unique tables in the database.

Comment: If you "view source" of the web page do you see the blank records? Wondering if you might have non HTMLEncoded characters that are messing up the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Access Both ZINDEX with different variables. Try this join query.

```
SELECT
Scorecard_Measure.Measure,
Scorecard_Measure.Target,
Scorecard_Measure.YTD,
Scorecard_Measure.Status,
Scorecard_Measure.Explanation,
Scorecard_Measure.Division,
Scorecard_Measure.ZIndex as MZIndex,
Scorecard_Measure.LastUpdated,
Scorecard_Measure.ID,
Scorecard_Objectives.Details,
Scorecard_Objectives.ZIndex as OZIndex,
Scorecard_ObjectiveCats.IdentityLetter
FROM
Scorecard_Measure INNER JOIN Scorecard_Objectives 
ON Scorecard_Measure.ObjID=Scorecard_Objectives.ID
AND Scorecard_Measure.FiscalYear = '2011'
AND Scorecard_Measure.Publish='Y'
INNER JOIN Scorecard_ObjectiveCats 
ON Scorecard_Objectives.ObjCatID = Scorecard_ObjectiveCats.ID
ORDER BY Scorecard_Measure.LastUpdated DESC
```